# The caption overlapping with the table and figures

Tags: tables, captions

How should I fix the following? The caption overlaps with either of figure and tables.

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{\label{tab:compareResult1}
Results of Ablation Studies: Accuracy of different input settings on KenyanFood13.}
\vspace*{-.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|r|r|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method}}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test Accuracy}}                \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                 &\textbf{Top-1} & \textbf{Top-3} \\ \hline\hline
Image only          &    73.18\%$\pm$ 0.79\%  &  92.04\%$\pm$ 0.44\% \\ \hline
Caption only                &    65.30\%$\pm$ 1.70\%     &   83.68\%$\pm$ 1.55\%   \\ \hline\hline
{\bf Ours:} Image + Caption               &    81.04\%$\pm$ 0.86\%     &  95.95\%$\pm$ 0.44\%   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-0.2cm}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: this is caused by your `\vspace*` commands ... This is their meaning ... to force a negative space...

Comment: Any news? Now one from received questions is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a negative `\vspace` is most likely the cause behind the overlapping of the `\caption` and your `tabular`.

The following removes this and uses a [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) representation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Results of Ablation Studies: Accuracy of different input settings on KenyanFood13.}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
    \toprule
                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Test accuracy} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    \textbf{Method}                &    \textbf{Top-1}    &    \textbf{Top-3}    \\
    \midrule
    Image only                     & $73.18\% \pm 0.79\%$ & $92.04\% \pm 0.44\%$ \\
    Caption only                   & $65.30\% \pm 1.70\%$ & $83.68\% \pm 1.55\%$ \\
    \textbf{Ours:} Image + Caption & $81.04\% \pm 0.86\%$ & $95.95\% \pm 0.44\%$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may point you in the right direction

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
                \begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:compareResult1}
Results of Ablation Studies: Accuracy of different input settings on KenyanFood13.}

% \vspace*{-.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method}}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test Accuracy}}                          \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                                 &\textbf{Top-1}                                 & \textbf{Top-3}       \\ \hline\hline
Image only                                       &    73.18\%$\pm$ 0.79\%                        &  92.04\%$\pm$ 0.44\%     \\ \hline
Caption only                                     &    65.30\%$\pm$ 1.70\%                        &   83.68\%$\pm$ 1.55\%   \\ \hline\hline
{\bf Ours:} Image + Caption                      &    81.04\%$\pm$ 0.86\%                        &  95.95\%$\pm$ 0.44\%   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
% \vspace*{-0.2cm}
\caption{\label{tab:compareResult1}
Results of Ablation Studies: Accuracy of different input settings on KenyanFood13.}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you're loading all of those packages yet you're only using one of them? Also, consider not using `\bf` and rather `\bfseries`. Finally, using the same `\label` twice is not a good suggestion, even if this is just an example.

Comment: Nope --no reason--just for the negative points i suppose ha ha